# Is there a way to write in a textarea on a web page but without using selenium or a webdriver?

Tags: python

I just need a way to write to the textdoc.co textarea but without drivers

Thank for help guys!

tried with a post request:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://textdoc.co/###url doc###'
payload = {'txt-doc': 'Hello World'}
response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    textarea = soup.find('textarea', {'id': 'txt-doc'})
    if textarea is not None:
        print('Text successfully inserted')
    else:
        print('Element with id "txt-doc" not found')
else:
    print('Error sending request')
```

But it just prints me error sending requests

Do you think there is another way?

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make sense.  If you don't have a browser, then no one has rendered the page, and there is no `<textarea>` control to fill in.  What do you plan to do with this?  If you're going to submit these changes to the site, then you can simulate the actions taken by the "Submit" button and send a `POST` request with your changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate typing, clicking, open URL, etc with [Pyppeteer](https://pyppeteer.github.io/pyppeteer/index.html). For example:

```py
from pyppeteer import launch
import time
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()

async def main():
    browser = await launch({
        "headless": False
    })
    page = await browser.newPage()
    id_doc = '###url doc###'
    await page.goto('https://textdoc.co/'+id_doc)
    title = 'My Title'
    description = 'My Description'
    await page.evaluate('()=>{ document.querySelector("input#txt-name").value = "" }')
    await page.click('input#txt-name')
    await page.type('input#txt-name', title)
    await page.evaluate('()=>{ document.querySelector("textarea#txt-doc").value = "" }')
    await page.click('textarea#txt-doc')
    await page.type('textarea#txt-doc', description)
    time.sleep(2)  # sleep 2 seconds
    await page.click('main')
    time.sleep(2)  # sleep 2 seconds
    # await page.click('button[title="Download"]')
    await page.evaluate('()=>{ location.href = "https://textdoc.co/home/download/'+id_doc+'"}')
    time.sleep(10)  # sleep 10 seconds
    await browser.close()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```